# Create PKCS#1 formatted RSA key using OpenSSL v3.0.0

Tags: openssl, pkcs#1

I wanted to confirm if we can create PKCS#1/traditional formatted RSA keys using version **3.0.0** of OpenSSL. I guess following command is giving me the output in PKCS#8 format.
**openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048**

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Using OpenSSL 3.0, you can use the `-traditional` switch to get the older format for your output, both for the `openssl rsa` and `openssl genrsa` subcommands. Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly(PKCS#8):

```
openssl genpkey -out rsakey.pem -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
cat rsakey.pem 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
base64_encode xxx
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

openSSL 1.1.1(PKCS#1)

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048

cat server.key 

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
base64_encode xxx
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

openssl pkcs8 to pkcs1 command

```
openssl rsa -in rsakey.pem -out rsakey_pkcs1.pem
cat rsakey_pkcs1.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
base64_encode xxx
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with openssl 3.0 which cannot convert PKCS #8 private keys into PKCS #1 keys, at least on Ubuntu. The issue may come from the upstream project.